# what is the basic steps to build social network website?

Tags: networking, social-networking

what is the basic steps to build social network without using the websites that provide a free social network?
Is it need a separate server? ok I can't buy the server !
How do I can start without spend any money?

Comment: This is way too vague of a question.  What do you want the website to do?

Comment: Please note that this is not a programming question

Comment: Please clarify if you need programming help designing a website/portal. You can't create a social network for free if you say you don't want to consume the websites that might offer free social network services.

Comment: this is a very large project, and will require many steps, take it on step at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with a dedicated server(if you can get a static IP from your internet provider you can host it yourself from your computer, or try some free servers, but they won't be dedicated), a database(if you are going for free MYSQL or SQL Express), some form of GUI that connects to the database showing data (asp.net with visual studios express is what I would prefer).  And then just like that you have a networking site...